Progress bar in vba
I'm working with a macro that takes a long time to execute (>1 min) and I want to improve it by adding a progressbar.
I've followed multiple tutorials that all say to create a userform, add an element and modify its width (like here : https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html).
I tried something similar, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code :
' Montrer la barre d'avancement
    ProgressBar.Show
    
    For i = 1 To catia.Documents.Count ' Parcourir l'ensemble des documents en mémoire
        ' À Chaque tour de boucle For, mettre à jour la barre de progression
        CurrentpctComplete = Int(i / catia.Documents.Count)
        BarProgress (CurrentpctComplete)
    
        ' Some stuff with CATIA Documents
    Next i

And here is my update function
Sub BarProgress(pctComplete As Single)
    ProgressBar.Text.Caption = pctComplete & "% Completed"
    ProgressBar.Bar.Width = pctComplete * 2
    ProgressBar.Repaint
    DoEvents
End Sub


And the result is that the popup is shown at the beginning of the For loop and then everything freeze. The program continues only if I click the red cross of the popup.
I tried to move the update snippet in the for loop but it does nothing*.

According to the link you provided you have to put the code which does actually do the work into the Activateevent. It seems that you did not do that. Is my guess correct?

Maybe use this ProgressBar. It has the ability to Cancel and can run both Modal and Modeless.

From your first code snippet it seems you've moved the ProgressBar.Show code to within your main module. As per the tutorial this code should be called from the ProgressBar_Activate() within the userform module, for the code to be run within the userform instance. Otherwise the userform is initiated, executes no code, and stops, which is the result you're getting. Then, until the userform is completed and removed, the rest of the code is interrupted by the open userform and will not progress until it is closed.
If you move the ProgressBar.Show snippet to whatever trigger you have to initiate this code, and call the rest of the main code sub from within the ProgressBar_Activate() on your userform module, it should run as expected.

The reason nothing happens is that currentpctComplete is always 0 (except if you reach the last document) because Int(i / catia.Documents.Count) is 0 as long as i is less than the document count.
If you want to display percentages, use
Dim CurrentpctComplete As Long
CurrentpctComplete = Int(100 * i / catia.Documents.Count)

Now CurrentpctComplete will get a value between 0 and 100 - and you should pass an integer (use data type Long).
Sub BarProgress(pctComplete As Long)
    ...
End Sub

Or pass the fraction to the progress bar form and let the form decide what to do with it:
Dim CurrentpctComplete As Double
CurrentpctComplete = i / catia.Documents.Count

Now CurrentpctComplete will get a value between 0 and 1 - use Single or Double as data type.
Sub BarProgress(complete As Double)
    Dim pctComplete as Long
    pctComplete = CLng(100 * complete)
    (...)
End Sub

